# Testng: parallel testing issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I have tried to create the simple testcases which running in parallel several threads(for example, 3) at the same time by using `testng`, but I have faced an issue. During testing, I have expected that `System.out.println()` will put into a console `"test"`sentences for each thread, but it didn't happen. You can find below the code which uses in my сase:

```
public class TestC {
   @Test(invocationCount = 3,  threadPoolSize = 3)
   public static void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("test");
   }
}
```

Could you help me to find out the root of the problem and suggest the solution to this issue?
I have added the picture.
[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce - when I run this I get the word "test" outputted three times. Can you perhaps share a screenshot of your execution?

Comment: I have added the picture above. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test seems to be working correctly. The issue here is all down to how IntelliJ IDEA handles test output. If you move your focus to "TestC" instead of an individual test run like you have in your screenshot, you should see the output:

[image]